# blender viewport and render are different

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

i was trying to follow the tutorial on youtube (Blender 3D - уроки) but my cycles render result doesn't picture water the same as at viewport shading.
This happens with other projects as well, the result is always different.
Thank you for any help!

[image]

[image]

Comment: At a guess it looks to me like something in (or not in) your World Shader.  It can be a good idea to post your blend file, or a truncated version of it that has the problem. The Blender StackExchange has its own service to share blend files: blend-exchange.com/help

Comment: This looks like there is an object that intersects with the water. Double check that you haven't hidden an object in the viewport, but forgot to hide it for the render.